# C# Как отображать процент загрузки на progress bar

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, download, httpwebrequest

Есть такой код, который скачивает и докачивает файл. Как можно отображать процесс скачивание на прогресс бар

```
static void DownloadFile(string sSourceURL, string sDestinationPath)
{
    long iFileSize = 0;
    int iBufferSize = 1024;
    iBufferSize *= 1000;
    long iExistLen = 0;
    System.IO.FileStream saveFileStream;
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(sDestinationPath))
    {
        System.IO.FileInfo fINfo =
           new System.IO.FileInfo(sDestinationPath);
        iExistLen = fINfo.Length;
    }
    if (iExistLen > 0)
        saveFileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(sDestinationPath,
          System.IO.FileMode.Append, System.IO.FileAccess.Write,
          System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);
    else
        saveFileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(sDestinationPath,
          System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write,
          System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);

    System.Net.HttpWebRequest hwRq;
    System.Net.HttpWebResponse hwRes;
    hwRq = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(sSourceURL);
    hwRq.AddRange((int)iExistLen);
    System.IO.Stream smRespStream;
    hwRes = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)hwRq.GetResponse();
    smRespStream = hwRes.GetResponseStream();

    iFileSize = hwRes.ContentLength;

    int iByteSize;
    byte[] downBuffer = new byte[iBufferSize];

    while ((iByteSize = smRespStream.Read(downBuffer, 0, downBuffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        saveFileStream.Write(downBuffer, 0, iByteSize);
    }
    saveFileStream.Close();

}
```

Comment: Для скачки файла можно воспользоватся классом `WebClient`. У него есть событие `DownloadProgressChanged`, которое срабатывает при изменении прогресса загрузки. Останется только подписатся на это событие и в подписчике обновлять ваш `ProgressBar`.

Comment: winforms или wpf?

Comment: -aepot WindowsForm

Comment: @danrom11 - Подскажи пожалуйста как в выше предоставленном коде добавить сколько скачено мб из скольки, поскольку всегда использовал WebClient сегодня наткнулся на эту тему, и не совсем понимаю как в твоем коде что реализовано.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш код синхронный, интерфейс просто не будет обновляться пока он работает. Придется либо втыкать костыли в виде опасного `Application.DoEvents()` либо написать нормальный асинхронный метод, что я и сделал.

На самом деле, если поискать, примеров в гугле очень много, разных, в том числе и тот, который приведен в вопросе. Но все они сильно устаревшие, и многие не поддерживают докачку, либо портят файл при докачке.

К тому же [`HttpWebRequest`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=netframework-4.8) устарел.

> Не рекомендуется использовать `HttpWebRequest` для новой разработки. Вместо этого используйте класс [`HttpClient`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8).

Вот пример для WinForms с использованием `HttpClient`.

- Грузит файл асинхронно и сохраняет на диск
- Докачивает, если часть файла уже загружена
- По нажатию кнопки **Cancel** можно остановить загрузку и продолжить потом повторным нажатием кнопки **Download**
- `button1` - кнопка **Download**, `button2` - кнопка **Cancel**, `progressBar1` - прогресс бар
- реализована базовая обработка ошибок
- реализован отчет о прогрессе с помощью интерфейса `IProgress` и класса `Progress`

Полный код приложения.

```csharp
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button2.Enabled = false; // по умолчанию закачка не активна, кнопку `Cancel` выключаем
    }

    // HttpClient создается один раз на всё время работы приложения
    private static readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

    // Токен отмены служит для прерывания работы загрузчика в любой момент
    private CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    // метод универсален, проверен в .NET Core и .NET Framework
    private async Task DownloadAndSaveFileAsync(string url, string path, IProgress<int> status, CancellationToken token)
    {
        const int bufferLength = 8192;
        long currentPosition = File.Exists(path) ? new FileInfo(path).Length : 0;

        using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url))
        {
            request.Headers.Range = new RangeHeaderValue(currentPosition, null);
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, token).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                using (Stream responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                {
                    long contentLength = currentPosition + response.Content.Headers.ContentLength ?? 0;
                    int progress = -1;
                    int oldProgress;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
                    int bytesReceived;
                    while ((bytesReceived = await responseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, bufferLength, token).ConfigureAwait(false)) > 0)
                    {
                        await fs.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesReceived, token).ConfigureAwait(false);

                        currentPosition += bytesReceived;
                        oldProgress = progress;
                        progress = (int)(currentPosition * 100 / contentLength);
                        // так как значение от 0 до 100, нет особого смысла повтороно обновлять интерфейс, если значение не изменилось.
                        if (oldProgress != progress)
                        {
                            status?.Report(progress);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // обратите внимание на async здесь
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_cts != null)
            return;
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = true;

        using (_cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            try
            {
                // укажите здесь нужный URL и путь к файлу
                // обратите внимение на new Progress<int>(v => progressBar1.Value = v) - оно и меняет значение прогресс бара во время загрузки
                await DownloadAndSaveFileAsync("https://example.org/file.txt", "file.txt", new Progress<int>(v => progressBar1.Value = v), _cts.Token);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Message.Contains("416")) // 416 (Requested Range Not Satisfiable)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Файл уже закачан");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "HttpRequestException");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), ex.GetType().Name);
            }
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
        }
        _cts = null;
        button1.Enabled = true;
        button2.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_cts != null && !_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
            _cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

В данном примере есть один недостаток, он не будет работать если веб-сервер не поддерживает докачку файла. Но вы можете его доработать.

Comment: Не подскажите, как получать проценты сколько скачено, или лучше сколько скачено мб из скольки

Comment: @danrom11 Так здесь и показываются проценты. Если вам нужны мегабайты, нужно немного переделать.

Comment: @danrom11 можно же так модифицировать с процентами, например в `label1`: `new Progress<int>(v => { progressBar1.Value = v; label1.Text = v + "%" })`.

Comment: Да я понял с процентами, что то тупонул, уже сделал их, спасибо большое

Comment: aepot, а можно ли сделать ограничение на скорость скачивания ?

Comment: @danrom11 [можно](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18243/Bandwidth-throttling), делайте :)

Comment: @danrom11 вот еще [ссылка](https://gist.github.com/passy/637319)

Comment: спасибо ещё раз :)