# Заполнение ProgressBar

Tags: c#, winforms, ftp, progress-bar

Есть такой метод:

```
public static async void DownloadFile(string filename, IProgress<decimal> progress)
{
    progress.Report(0m);

    using (WebClient request = new WebClient())
    {
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password");

        byte[] fileData = request.DownloadData("ftp://...." + filename);

        var pathNormalize = $"{MyPath.Desktop}\\{filename}".Replace("\r", string.Empty);

        using (var file = File.Create(pathNormalize))
        {
            await file.WriteAsync(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
            var percent = 100m * ((decimal)file.Position / file.Length);
            progress.Report(percent);
        }
    }
}
```

Вызываю так:

```
var progress = new Progress<decimal>((p) =>
{
    progressBar1.Value = (int)Convert.ToDecimal(p)));

    if (progressBar1.Value >= progressBar1.Maximum)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        MessageBox.Show("Completed!");
    }
});

FTP.DownloadFile(name, progress);
```

Проблема:

При вызове метода `DownloadFile` блокируется основной поток и в конце значение `ProgressBar` становится `100`.

Если вызывать так:

```
Task.Run(() => FTP.DownloadFile(name, progress));
```

Основной поток не блокируется, но `ProgressBar` также перескакивает к значению `100`.

При всём при этом, после скачивание файла не показывает текст `Completed!`.

Нашел на просторах интернета уже не один пример скачивания файла с `FTP`, но ни один так и не удалось подружить с `ProgessBar`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема. Пытаюсь разобраться уже много времени.

upd:

```
public static void DownloadFile(string filename, DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler DownloadProgressChanged, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler DownloadCompleted)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        using (WebClient request = new WebClient())
        {
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password");
            request.DownloadProgressChanged += DownloadProgressChanged;
            request.DownloadFileCompleted += DownloadCompleted;

            var pathNormalize = $"{MyPath.Desktop}\\{filename}".Replace("\r", string.Empty);
            request.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("ftp://....." + filename), pathNormalize);
        }
    });
    thread.Start();
}

private void DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    });
}

private void DownloadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
        MessageBox.Show("Completed!");
    });
}
```

Comment: Из другого потока с элементами интерфейса нужно работать через `Invoke`.

Comment: И у вас прогресс показывается не скачивания файла, а записи на диск. Если файл небольшой, то он будет быстро перескакивать на 100.

Comment: @ГеннадийП, вот попробовал сделать по другому. Вроде бы должен показывать прогресс скачивания, а не записи. Но проблема та же. Единственное, `Completed!` теперь показывает. (обновил первый пост)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [C# Как отображать процент загрузки на progress bar](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1133993/c-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-progress-bar)

Comment: Не надо оборачивать в дополнительный поток вебклиент с вызовом `DownloadFileAsync`, т. к. он и так будет выполняться асинхронно.

Comment: Вот готовый велосипед [FluentFTP](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentFTP/). Устанавливайте NuGet пакет, пробуйте.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалось в том, что при скачивании с `FTP` с отображением прогресса, нужно для начала узнать размер файла.

Вот рабочий код:

```
public static void DownloadFile(string filename, DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler DownloadProgressChanged, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler DownloadCompleted)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://......" + filename);
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
        var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            MainForm.bytes = response.ContentLength;
        }

        using (WebClient request_ = new WebClient())
        {
            request_.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password");
            request_.DownloadProgressChanged += DownloadProgressChanged;
            request_.DownloadFileCompleted += DownloadCompleted;

            var pathNormalize = $"{MyPath.Desktop}\\{filename}".Replace("\r", string.Empty);
            request_.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("ftp://....." + filename), pathNormalize);
        }
    });
    thread.Start();
}

private void DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
        progressBar1.Value = (int)(((float)e.BytesReceived / (float)bytes) * 100.0);
    });
}

private void DownloadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
        MessageBox.Show("Completed!");
    });
}

//где-то вызов
FTP.DownloadFile(name, DownloadProgressChanged, DownloadCompleted);
```

Comment: Использовать одновременно и `WebRequest`, и `WebClient` - как-то странно и вообще незачем.

Comment: Обратите внимание на то что вы используете сильно устаревший код. Ваш сервер точно не умеет отдавать файлы по http?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, как иначе узнать размер перед загрузкой?

Comment: @aepot, в данный момент — может, но в будущем — не сможет.

Comment: @Максим вы же в курсе, что большинство провайдеров не поддерживает FTP, просто провайдерский NAT не пропускает FTP трафик. Приходится работать в пассивном режиме. Так вот, если вам нужно скачивать файлы с сервера, то это только HTTP. Если вам нужно эти файлы туда заливать, то можно использовать любой толковый FTP клиент - FileZilla или Total Commander. На своих серверах я держу FTP только именно для заливки данных на сервер, и то планирую от него отказаться, слишком много сетевых проблем. Вы уверены в том, что вы делаете?

Comment: К вашему вопросу я прилинковал качалку по HTTP с возможностью докачки, совсем недавно написал с нуля ее, рекомендую попробовать. Если же вам принципиален FTP, то расскажите, почему. Этому протоколу пора уже покоиться с миром. Еще, если не слышали, есть такая очень попалярная штука - WebDAV.

Comment: @aepot, потому что мне по максимум нужно упростить работу с загрузкой/выгрузкой файлов на FTP сервер. То есть, открыл программу — сразу видишь список файлов, нажал добавить — файл загрузился, нажал скачать — файл скачался. И ещё, выбранный файл перед загрузкой добавляется в архив с паролем.. то есть, если все эти действия делать в ручную, это очень муторно и долго.

Comment: То есть, вы делаете именно свой FTP клиент, а не просто скачиваете файлы, так? Что у вас на стороне сервера, proftpd? У вас используется шифрование FTP соединения? В вопросе вы рассматриваете только метод скачивания файлов, при этом не рассматриваете ни получение списка файлов, не навигацию по директориям, не заливку файла на сервер, не работу с правами доступа к файлам. Или с этим у вас все хорошо? Пока я вижу, что ваш логин и пароль от сервера просто утащат хакеры, так как соединение не зашифровано. Вы же используете не тот же самый логин и пароль, что и от ssh?

Comment: Если кратко, ошибка которую я сейчас вижу, то вы каждый раз устанавливаете новое FTP соединение при закачке файла, это значит, что вы каждый раз передаете логин и пароль на сервер в открытом виде. Я бы рекомендовал использовать максимум 2 соединения, одно для навигации по каталогам, второе для фоновой передачи данных. Чтобы качать или заливать файлы в уже открытом соединении, тогда не придется хотя-бы так часто передавать логин и пароль. Но подумайте о шифровании, у меня FTP соединение шифруется с помощью SSL сертификата.

Comment: @aepot, проблем с получением списка файлов, загрузкой файлов, не возникло. Логин и пароль, разумеется, в таком виде в котором есть — хранится не будет. И да, в данный момент я использовал логин/пароль что и от ssh. Но это просто чтобы отладить работу, реализовать необходимые задачи. А вот теперь уже, буду думать над защитой. Сразу отвечу на Ваш второй коммент: уже установил соединение один раз при открытии программы, спасибо. А вот SSL сертификата, у меня, к сожалению, нет.

Comment: SSL сертификат можете получить бесплатно, в автоматическом режиме, у Let's Ecrypt. У вас же есть какой-то домен и HTTP сервер, сертификат один и тот же подойдет, и для HTTP, и для FTP. Заодно и самый настоящий HTTPS у вас заработает.

Comment: Есть еще один способ избавиться от FTP,  если вы не планируете давать FTP пользователям - это SCP, передача файлов по SSH. Есть такой клиент WinSCP, в комплекте с PuTTY идет, от тех же разработчиков. Безопасная передача файлов, и сертификат не потребуется. Возможно и для C# есть библиотеки, я бы рекомендовал вам поискать так же в этом направлении.

Comment: Вот, нашел - [SSH.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SSH.NET)