# C# Как скачать ЦЕЛУЮ папку со всеми файлами?

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, файлы, download, webclient

Мне необходимо скачать из сети папку с большим количеством файлов в ней. Соответственно, я не могу скачивать каждый файл по одиночке, но как иначе? Я пробовал `DownloadData` метод, но он, естественно не помог.
Сама операция должна выглядеть вот так (последний вариант с `DownloadData`):

```
await Task.Run(() => webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += new DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler(Completed));
await Task.Run(() => webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new
DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged));
await Task.Run(() => Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaminп/" + season));
await Task.Run(() => webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("http://mysite.ru/season/" + season), @"C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/" + season));
```

Comment: А где массив или список того, что надо грузить? Покажите больше кода. Что за приложение, консоль?

Comment: 1. `WebClient` устарел, замените его на `HttpClient`. 2. Не как, ибо должен быть список файлов, который вы будете хранить у себя и по которому будете производить операцию загрузки. Если сервер такое не дает, то как вы собираетесь качать то о чем у вас нет информации? Если же сервер дает такой список, то считывайте его и циклом по очереди качайте чтоб ускорить - качайте пару файлов из списка за раз. 3. Что за ужас у вас тут с `Task.Run()`? Если задача нуждается в асинхронности, то ее и следует запускать, вот к примеру зачем вам асинхронно создавать директорию? Так что не пихайте async везде!

Comment: [Вот решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1134235/373567) для закачки одного файла с отчетом о прогрессе и докачкой. Чтобы показать решение для закачки нескольких файлов, мне нужны ответы на вопросы, обозначенные выше.