# Вопрос с скачиванием файлов в папку

Tags: c#, download

сделал я значит скачивание файлов в папку, но, оно почему-то как-то очень криво работает. Не понимаю что не так.
Значит залил файлы которые я хочу скачивать на appserv, а именно в отдельную папку, папка работает, открывается, всё отлично, но.
Как только приложение моё начинает скачивание, сразу возникают проблемы, теперь конкретно о них:

- При скачивании файла, а именно в папку которую пользователь указал заранее, происходит скачивание, спустя 2-3 скачаных файла вылетает приложение в ошибку.
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

  ```
            var d = new Downloader(download_mp_link, new MPDownloadProvider(), needToDownloadSize);
            d.ProgressChanged += OnProgressChangedMP;
            d.StartDownload += OnStartDownloadMP;
            await d.DownloadFiles("E:\\download");


    public async Task DownloadFiles(string path)
    {
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.DownloadProgressChanged += Wc_DownloadProgressChanged;
            foreach (var fileName in downloadProvider.Files)
            {
                CreateNeccessaryDirs(path + @"\" + fileName.Value);
                if (File.Exists(path + @"\" + fileName.Value))
                {
                    continue; 
                }
                prevDownloadedSize = 0L;
                StartDownload?.Invoke(this, new StartDownloadFileArgs { FileName = fileName.Value });
                stopwatch.Restart();
                await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(master_url + "/" + fileName.Key), path + @"\" + fileName.Value);
                stopwatch.Stop();
            }
            ProgressChanged?.Invoke(this, new Events.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs() { NewPercentage = 100 });
        }
    }
  ```

Comment: `WebClient` в C# является **устаревшим**, не советую (как и Microsoft) использовать его! По поводу вопроса: Вы говорите, что у вас "проблемы", а расписали лишь одну, и то ту проблему, которую мы вряд ли сможем как-либо воспроизвести. Если вам сервер пишет "Файла нет", то его там нет, значит эта ссылка временная. Тут надо разбираться с сервером, а не с этим кодом, что вы дали.

Comment: Что тогда иное использовать для скачивания?

Comment: Что тогда иное использовать для скачивания?

Comment: [пример качалки с отчетом о прогрессе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1134235/373567), даже с возможностью докачивать недокачанное.