# Вывод прогресс бара в другую форму c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Сделал установку в одном окне, вод код:

```
private void pictureBox5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string mpapartment = path + @"\update\x64\dlcpacks\mpapartment\dlc.rpf";

    string url = "SERVER";
    check();

    MessageBox.Show(mpapartment);
    MessageBox.Show("Загрузка началась.");
    wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), mpapartment);
            
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Form ifrm = new Form1();
    ifrm.Show(); // отображаем Form2
    this.Hide(); // скрываем Form1 (this - текущая форма)
}
```

Мне надо как-то вывести это все дело в другую форму с `ProgressBar`

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте метод в другой форме

```cs
public void SetProgress(int value)
{
    progressBar1.Value = value;
}
```

Потом измените основной

```cs
private void pictureBox5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string mpapartment = Path.Combine(path, @"update\x64\dlcpacks\mpapartment\dlc.rpf");

    string url = "SERVER";

    Form ifrm = new Form1();
    ifrm.Closed += (s, e) => this.Show();

    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => { ifrm.SetProgress(e.ProgressPercentage); };
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) => ifrm.Close();
    client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), mpapartment);
    
    ifrm.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

---

Есть кстати [решение получше, посовременнее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1134235/373567), с использовением `HttpClient` вместо устаревшего `WebClient` и нормальной асинхронностью.

Comment: у меня вылезает ошибка с переменной e. 
ifrm.Closed += (s, e) => this.Show();
            client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => { ifrm.SetProgress(e.ProgressPercentage); };
            client.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) => ifrm.Close();
            client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), mpapartment);

Comment: @1k237 а какая именно ошибка и в какой именно строке, вы конечно же не скажете? Вы уверены, что скопировали себе код правильно? И куда делся `WebClient client = new WebClient();`? Верните его на место.

Comment: SetProgress и в переменной e

Comment: @1k237 текст ошибки скажите, я не телепат.

Comment: Серьезность Код Описание Проект Файл Строка Состояние подавления
Ошибка CS0136 Локальная переменная или параметр с именем "e" нельзя объявить в данной области, так как это имя используется во включающей локальной области для определения локальной переменной или параметра newgui C:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\коран\чурка\newgui\newgui\Form2.cs 124 Активные

Comment: @1k237 ну переименуйте ее например `ea`