# Не скачиваются файлы, зависает поток

Tags: c#, файлы, httpclient, download

Либо зависает поток, либо пишет, что доступ к этому файлу заблокирован другим потоком. Хотя этого быть не может, т.к я использую `using`

Там проектик не большой, который я постоянно использую для разных парсингов сайта.
Поэтому код может быть грязноватый.

Можете сами посмотреть, просто создав папку `Work` на диске `C`

https://github.com/gokor8/Portak/tree/master

Я знаю, что бесполезно закрывать поток в `using` но сделал на всякий случай, для проверки.

Ошибку выдает в классе `HttpClient` в методах `Download`.

Вот так это выглядит, когда он виснет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сама ошибка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Класс в котором ошибка

```
public static class HttpClass
    {
        public static readonly string FirstPathLink;
        static int NumberImage = 0;
        public static readonly string SiteName;

        public static CookieContainer CookieContainer;
        private static HttpClientHandler handler;
        public static HttpClient Client;

        private static IConfiguration config;
        public static IBrowsingContext Context;

        static HttpClass()
        {
            CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = CookieContainer };
            Client = new HttpClient(handler)
            {
                Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3),
                BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.arrex.it/en/")
            };

            config = Configuration.Default;
            Context = BrowsingContext.New(config); //Client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Calam");
            SiteName = Cutter.Tram(Client.BaseAddress.Host.Replace(".", "").Replace(",", "") + 1);
            FirstPathLink = "https://" + Client.BaseAddress.Host + "/";
        }

        public static async Task<string> Download(string link)
        {
            string image = link;
            string konec1 = image.Substring(image.LastIndexOf("."), image.Length - image.LastIndexOf("."));

            if (!image.Contains("http"))
                image = FirstPathLink + image;

            Directory.CreateDirectory($@"C:\Work\{SiteName}\" + ExcelContainer.NA);

            string gg = "";

            var sourceStream = await Client.GetStreamAsync(new Uri(image));
            using (var targetStream = File.Create($@"C:\Work\{SiteName}\" + ExcelContainer.NA + @"\" + NumberImage + konec1))
            {
                await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(targetStream);
            }

            gg = $"/upload/staff/upload/staff/{SiteName}/" + ExcelContainer.NA + "/" + NumberImage + konec1 + ";\r\n";
            NumberImage++;
            return gg;
        }

        public static async Task<string> Download(string link, string konec1)
        {
            string image = link;

            if (!image.Contains("http"))
                image = FirstPathLink + image;

            Directory.CreateDirectory($@"C:\Work\{SiteName}\" + ExcelContainer.NA);

            string gg = "";

            var sourceStream = await Client.GetStreamAsync(new Uri(image));
            using (var targetStream = File.Create($@"C:\Work\{SiteName}\" + ExcelContainer.NA + @"\" + NumberImage + konec1))
            {
                await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(targetStream);
            }

            gg = $"/upload/staff/upload/staff/{SiteName}/" + ExcelContainer.NA + "/" + NumberImage + konec1 + ";\r\n";
            NumberImage++;
            return gg;
        }
    }
```

Comment: я походил по репозиторию,а можно добавить, в каком именно файле и методе выдаётся ошибка? чтобы на него глазами посмотреть, прежде чем делать git clone

Comment: Ошибку выдает в классе HttpClient в методах Download.`var sourceStream = await Client.GetStreamAsync(new Uri(image));
            using (var targetStream = File.Create($@"C:\Work\{SiteName}\" + ExcelContainer.NA + @"\" + NumberImage + konec1))
            {
                await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(targetStream);
                targetStream.Close();
            }`

Comment: Ну у меня сразу было подозрение, что без экселя там не обошлось, как только увидел using ExcelLibrary.SpreadSheet. Я ПОДООЗРЕВАЮ, что у Вас в памяти висит эксель и файл в нём открыт. А программа пытается этот файл модифицировать. Но, емлу Вам не трудно - дайте полный путь к ФАЙЛУ проекта, в котором происходит ошибка?

Comment: Думаете он потоку передачи в файл тоже мешает?

Comment: Хм, справедливое замечание! просто увидел Excel  в тексте эксепшена. А как насчет ссылки на кокретный файли и метод в прооекте, где возникает ошибка?

Comment: Я посмотрел еще раз. Исключение вызывается именно в https://github.com/gokor8/Portak/blob/master/Margaroli/Http/HttpClass.cs 77 строке

Comment: да, теперь вижу. Хм. надо подумать!

Comment: Весь необходимый код должен быть в вопросе! В каком методе возникает исключение, тот и покажите. Только ради всего святого, текстом, а не скриншотом!

Comment: На кой ставить значок `$` интерполяции, но не использовать её? Можно так, коротко и ясно: `$@"C:\Work\{SiteName}\{ExcelContainer.NA}\{NumberImage}{konec1}"`

Comment: `targetStream.Close();` не нужно делать, у вас же `using` - вы в курсе, как оно работает?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, я не могу весь код написать в вопрос, иначе тут будет каша, легче дать ссылку на код, который нужо запустить и будет ошибка

Comment: @aepot я знаю что не нужен, но я поставил его для проверки, потому что очень странно, что поток открыт в другом приложении, как мне программа пишет в ошибке

Comment: @GorgeFlow если пишет, значит открыт. Но зачем добавлять закрытие для и так закрываемого нормально потока, если проблема не в закрытии, а в открытии? Добавьте логирование, вероятно вы одновременно пытаетесь писать в один и тот же файл из нескольких потоков. Ставьте точки останова, отлаживайте. И еще я советую вам изучить очень полезный метод `Path.Combine` и за счет него избавиться от этой каши с конкатенацией строк для путей.

Comment: Здесь по сути нет явной проблемы в коде, вас спасет только отладка. От себя могу только посоветовать заглянуть в [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1217351/373567) и [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1134235/373567) примеры, вдруг что полезное для себя найдете.

Comment: Я вижу в коде вызовы метода `HttpClass.Download` без `await`. Статическое поле `NumberImage`, которое используется для имени файла, инкрементируется `++` без всяких блокировок. Возможно, в результате этого имя файла в разных тасках оказывается одинаковым.

Comment: Да, банально не хватает await'ов (в Lavabi.cs). NumberImage не при делах. / Код я не запускал. Просто глянул на гитхабе.

Comment: Все пофиксил, спасибо за помощь