# Использую DownloadFileAsync , но скачивается пустой файл

Tags: c#

Подскажите, пожалуйста.
С адреса https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Constants/Table/allascii.txt скачивается пустой файл.
С других адресов качаю без проблем.

Использую стандартный код на  C#

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{              
wc.DownloadProgressChanged += wc_DownloadProgressChanged;
wc.DownloadFileAsync(              
new Uri("https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Constants/Table/allascii.txt"),
@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\arhiv\fc1.html" );
 //while (wc.IsBusy) { }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы уничтожаете `WebClient` с помощью `using` до того как страница будет загружена. Поэтому и пусто.

Но если очень надо, то можно попробовать вот так:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadProgressChanged += wc_DownloadProgressChanged;
wc.DownloadDataCompleted += (s, e) => wc.Dispose();
wc.DownloadFileAsync(url, path);
```

Но вообще `WebClient` устарел, используйте `HttpClient`.

```cs
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    string text = await client.GetStringAsync("https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Constants/Table/allascii.txt");
    File.WriteAllText("file.txt", text);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Вывод в файл `file.txt`, начальные несколько строк:

```
             Fundamental Physical Constants --- Complete Listing
             2018 CODATA adjustment


  From:  http://physics.nist.gov/constants



  Quantity                                                       Value                 Uncertainty           Unit
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
alpha particle-electron mass ratio                          7294.299 541 42          0.000 000 24             
alpha particle mass                                         6.644 657 3357 e-27      0.000 000 0020 e-27      kg
alpha particle mass energy equivalent                       5.971 920 1914 e-10      0.000 000 0018 e-10      J
```

Вообще файл весит 40 килобайт, смысла отображать прогресс загрузки не вижу. Если же вам надо качать огромные файлы в несколько гигабайт, то докачка в случае разрыва соединения тоже бы не помешала - [вот пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1134235/373567).

Comment: Спасибо за рекомендации. Обошелся малой кровью. Добавил строку с SSL ( в инете нашел  совет) , без нее сервер не давал разрешения скачать файл.

Comment: @Андрей Endpoint конфигурация? Быть может у вас .NET Framework старый? Начиная с .NET Framework 4.6.1, проблемы с TLS не должно возникать. Если я угадал, то обновление версии фреймворка заставит все рабротать и без этой строчки.

Comment: Возможно, строка такая
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: @Андрей именно. Ставите новее версию фреймворка, например 4.7.2, удаляете строку, и все работает. Если это .NET Core 3 или .NET 5/6, то эта строка там в принципе не имеет никакого эффекта.