# Асинхронное копирование в купе с progressBar'om

Tags: c#, winforms, потоки-данных, async-await, progress-bar

На самом деле задача на половину выполнена, я имею готовое решение не без помощи `backgoundWorker:`

**Функция копирования:**

```
private void copy_file(string source_, string des)
        {
                FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(des, FileMode.Create);
                FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(source_, FileMode.Open);
                byte[] bt = new byte[1048756];
                int readByte;

                while ((readByte = fsIn.Read(bt, 0, bt.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    fsOut.Write(bt, 0, readByte);
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)(fsIn.Position * 100 / fsIn.Length));
                }
                fsIn.Close();
                fsOut.Close();
        }
```

**DoWork:**

```
private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            copy_file(server_path + filename, Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\" + filename);
        }
```

**RunWorkerCompleted:**

```
private void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
            {               
                err_msg.Text = "Файл находится на рабочем столе!";
            }
            else
            {
                err_msg.Text = "Произошла ошибка.";
            }
            download_sound.Enabled = true;           
        }
```

**ProgressChanged:**

```
private void Worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            err_msg.Text = progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";
        }
```

**Click Button:**

```
Worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Выше указанный метод отлично справляется, но при использовании этого метода в Асинхронных функциях(например `private async void button_click()`), я получаю эффект очередности потоков, эм... файл копируется - помещается в нужную папку - прогресс бар мгновенно заполняется. Пробовал копировать через сеть, та же беда. Но к счастью работает когда `async` у `btn` отсутствует.

### Теперь к сути:

Т.к. изначально мой план был использовать `async\await` методы, я перешел к такому виду копирования файлов:

```
public async Task CopyFilesAsync(StreamReader Source, StreamWriter Destination)
        {
            char[] buffer = new char[0x1000];
            int numRead;
            while ((numRead = await Source.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                await Destination.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, numRead);
            }
        }
```

_

```
public async Task CopyFile(string startDirectoy, string endDirectory)
        {
            using (StreamReader SourceReader = File.OpenText(startDirectoy))
            {
                using (StreamWriter DestinationWriter = File.CreateText(endDirectory))
                {
                    await CopyFilesAsync(SourceReader, DestinationWriter);
                    SourceReader.Close();
                    DestinationWriter.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Никак не могу сообразить каким образом мне заставить progressBar выполнять мою задачу.
Я так же не могу достучаться до StreamReader.Position использовать:

```
progressBar1.Value=(int)((StreamReader.BaseStream.Position/StreamReader.BaseStream.Length)*100);
```

у меня не вышло. ProgressBar работал у меня отдельно от всего >< Если есть пару советов, прошу их дать, буду очень благодарен!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пока залепил -> https://c-sharpcode.com/thread/csharp-progress-bar-in-synchronous-with-process-in-real-time/

Comment: Встреча эпох. BackgoundWorker зачем вообще? Это очень давно устаревший класс времен .NET 3.5, когда тасков не существовало. Есть же потоки, есть же асинхронность.

Comment: @aepot, да я согласен! Вот и решил использовать асинхронность, но немного не могу додуматься как заставить работать progress bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Был у меня пример [скачивания файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1134235/373567), почему бы не переписать его под копирование

- Копирует файл асинхронно
- По нажатию кнопки Cancel можно остановить копирование
- `button1` - кнопка Copy, `button2` - кнопка Cancel, `progressBar1` - прогресс бар
- реализован отчет о прогрессе с помощью интерфейса IProgress и класса Progress

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button2.Enabled = false;
    }

    // Токен отмены служит для прерывания работы копирования в любой момент
    private CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    private async Task CopyFileAsync(string srcPath, string dstPath, IProgress<int> status, CancellationToken token)
    {
        const int bufferLength = 16384;

        using FileStream src = File.OpenRead(srcPath);
        using FileStream dst = File.Create(dstPath);
        long currentPosition = 0;
        long contentLength = src.Length;
        int progress = -1;
        int oldProgress;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
        int bytesReceived;
        while ((bytesReceived = await src.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, bufferLength, token).ConfigureAwait(false)) > 0)
        {
            await dst.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesReceived, token).ConfigureAwait(false);

            currentPosition += bytesReceived;
            oldProgress = progress;
            progress = (int)(currentPosition * 100 / contentLength);
            // так как значение от 0 до 100, нет особого смысла повтороно обновлять интерфейс, если значение не изменилось.
            if (oldProgress != progress)
            {
                status?.Report(progress);
            }
        }
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_cts != null)
            return;
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = true;

        using (_cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            try
            {
                await CopyFileAsync("file1.txt", "file2.txt", new Progress<int>(v => { progressBar1.Value = v; }), _cts.Token);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException) { } // была отмена, ничего не делать
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), ex.GetType().Name);
            }
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
        }
        _cts = null;

        button1.Enabled = true;
        button2.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _cts?.Cancel();
    }
}
```

---

Чтобы прогресс обновлялся с учетом медленной анимации прогресс-бара винформ

```
private async Task CopyFileAsync(string srcPath, string dstPath, IProgress<int> status, CancellationToken token)
{
    const int bufferLength = 16384;

    using FileStream src = File.OpenRead(srcPath);
    using FileStream dst = File.Create(dstPath);
    long currentPosition = 0;
    long contentLength = src.Length;
    int progress = -1;
    int oldProgress;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
    int bytesReceived;

    long elapsed = 0;
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    while ((bytesReceived = await src.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, bufferLength, token).ConfigureAwait(false)) > 0)
    {
        await dst.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesReceived, token).ConfigureAwait(false);

        currentPosition += bytesReceived;
        oldProgress = progress;
        progress = (int)(currentPosition * 100 / contentLength);
        
        // 1 / 30 = 0.033 - 30 кадров в секунду
        if (oldProgress != progress && (progress == 100 || sw.ElapsedMilliseconds - 33 > elapsed))
        {
            status?.Report(progress);
            elapsed = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Совет от @PavelMayorov стартовать копирование сразу в пуле потоков можно реализовать вот так

```
IProgress<int> status = new Progress<int>(v => { progressBar1.Value = v; });
await Task.Run(() => CopyFileAsync("file1.txt", "file2.txt", status, _cts.Token));
```

Comment: Да это работает в сети. но если я делаю это на пк сервера(бд), то скачка происходит много быстрее нежели движение прогрес бара, с тем же backgroundworker все выглядело более правдоподобно. хотелось бы узнать почему так ?

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato что значит на пк сервера? сервер это такой же компьютер, как любой другой. Никаких отклонений здесь технически быть не может, вы же видите код, он вычисляет фактические размеры. Если вы к серверу через RDP подключаетесь, то задержка может быть вызвана самим RDP, то есть изображение рабочего стола поступает по RDP с задержкой, и само приложение здесь вообще не при чем.

Comment: sql server на пк - 1, я развернул между несколькими пк - 2,3,4 - сеть. скачивая на любом из {2,3,4} - время на скачку прогресс бара выглядит достоверно. Но если я используя приложение на пк - 1 и фактически копирую с папки в папку файлы - прогресс бар ведет себя не верно. Файл копируется молниеносно, и я могу им пользоваться ещё до того как прогресс бар закончил свой путь. Я об этом, но это не так важно, мне просто стало интересно причина такого поведения - ответ думаю в том что вычисление большого размера файла занимает время у функции. файл ~ 500mb

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato сколько секунд прогресс бар еще продолжает свое движение? `ответ думаю в том что вычисление большого размера` нет, не в этом.

Comment: обновил вопрос gif. По факту появления файла на рабочем столе, я могу им пользоваться, остальное движение прогресс бара в пустую. за качество гиф сори, ковертер подвел

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato обновил ответ, попробуйте. Без прошлого костыля из коммента.

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato если у вас ожидаются большие файлы и высокие скорости копирования, увиличте размер буфера с `16384` до `65536`, это поднимет скорости копирования и снизит нагрузку на проц, но выше лучше не поднимайте, так как удваивание этого размера сделает массив буфера "большим" и его [по-особому](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap) будет обрабатывать сборщик мусора.

Comment: @aepot у вас CopyFileAsync работает в потоке UI, оттого и приколы с анимацией прогрессбара. Надо его в Task.Run обернуть (и не забыть что `new Progress` оборачивать нельзя)

Comment: @PavelMayorov не надо Task.Run, оно асинхронное, а вот про IProgress вы верно подметили. Ща помотрю, как подправить. Стоп, там `ConfigureAwait(false)` оно не работает в UI потоке, оно там только стартует, так что ничего менять не надо.

Comment: @aepot а, не заметил `ConfigureAwait`. Однако, `Task.Run` все равно лучше, поскольку позволяет открывать файлы (и закрывать их!) тоже асинхронно. Вы же в курсе, что в момент открытия или закрытия файла антивирус может решить синхронно проверить его на вирусы?

Comment: @PavelMayorov не уверен, что превентивное запихивание всего этого добра в пул займет меньше времени, чем открытие 2 файловых дескрипторов. То есть я бы согласился, если бы это вызывало реальный визуальный лаг на форме. В любом случае, это улучшение не связано с проблемой анимации прогрессбара в винформах.

Comment: @PavelMayorov дополнил ответ.

Comment: @aepot представьте что один из файлов находится на сетевом диске (а кнопка "скачать" на гифке намекает на это). В таком случае при сетевых проблемах открытие файла в потоке UI именно что вызовет заметный на глаз лаг формы.

Comment: @PavelMayorov это и так понятно, но это не значит, что я должен угадывать все нюансы, и даже те, что автор не озвучил и не планировал озвучивать.

Comment: Всем вовлеченным - спасибо! Много пищи для изучения и размышления:) Ответ я получил :)

Comment: Все работает, только var sw = StopWatch.StartNew(); -> var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew(); Подключить using System.Diagnostics;

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato код на коленке писал, простите :)

Comment: @aepot, не за что извиняться, ты очень крут, раз такое можете писать с колена :)