# Сменить WebClient на httpClient

Tags: c#, httpclient, webclient

Имеется вот такое решение, как оно будет выглядеть с использованием HttpClient?

```
        public async Task DownloadFiles(string path)
        {
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.DownloadProgressChanged += Wc_DownloadProgressChanged;
                foreach (var fileName in downloadProvider.Files)
                {
                    CreateNeccessaryDirs(path + @"\" + fileName.Value);
                    if (File.Exists(path + @"\" + fileName.Value))
                    {
                        continue; 
                    }
                    prevDownloadedSize = 0L;
                    StartDownload?.Invoke(this, new StartDownloadFileArgs { FileName = fileName.Value });
                    stopwatch.Restart();
                    await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(master_url + "/" + fileName.Key), path + @"\" + fileName.Value);
                    stopwatch.Stop();
                }
                ProgressChanged?.Invoke(this, new Events.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs() { NewPercentage = 100 });
            }
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661652/progress-bar-with-httpclient

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1134235/373567 вот, полный фарш

Comment: @aepot так а если у меня группа файлов? Я что-то не пойму, и не могу найти каких-то решений этого вопроса.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567