# Как синхронизировать progressbar и WebClient.DownloadFileAsync?

Tags: c#

Есть вот такой код:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mime;
using ShellProgressBar;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Download();
    }

    static void Download()
    {
        const int totalTicks = 100;
        
        var options = new ProgressBarOptions
        {
            ProgressCharacter = '─',
            ProgressBarOnBottom = true
        };
        
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            var pbar = new ProgressBar(totalTicks, "Initial message", options);
            wc.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => { pbar.Tick(e.ProgressPercentage,"Download XML Plugin..."); };
            wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://dev.osel.pp.ua/Consulo/Plugins/com.intellij.xml_2961.zip"),"/home/ketronix/xml.tar.gz");
            Console.ReadKey();
        };
    }
}
```

Он то работает, но я хочу чтобы по окончанию загрузки программа прекращала работу. Если другими словами - сейчас программа после загрузки ждет нажатия enter чтобы закрытся, как дальше нет никакого кода, можно сделать так чтобы она не ждала энтер, и если дальше кода нет, она вырубалась? А если код есть - продолжала работать? Всем спасибо.

Comment: `await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(...);`

Comment: Type 'void' is not awaitable, причем даже если я его асинхронным сделаю

Comment: Я исправил ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в лоб решать, то как-то так. Всегда решение подобных задач начинайте с чтения [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfileasync).

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        await DownloadAsync();
    }

    static async Task DownloadAsync()
    {
        var options = new ProgressBarOptions
        {
            ProgressCharacter = '─',
            ProgressBarOnBottom = true
        };
        
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) 
        {
            var pbar = new ProgressBar(totalTicks, "Initial message", options);
            wc.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => { pbar.Tick(e.ProgressPercentage,"Download XML Plugin..."); };
            await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri("http://dev.osel.pp.ua/Consulo/Plugins/com.intellij.xml_2961.zip"),"/home/ketronix/xml.tar.gz");
        };
    }
}
```

Имейте в виду, `WebClient` устарел и будет убран из .NET в будущем. Если интересует более современное решиение, то [вот так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1134235/373567).

Comment: Кхм... У WebClient есть метод `DownloadFileTaskAsync`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, спасибо, исправил ответ. На устаревших классах чего только не встретшь в названиях членов. Никогда бы не подумал, что этот метод существует, потому что его нормальное имя по факту занято. И что им мешало изменить void сигнатуру на Task при появлении TAP - тоже загадка.

Comment: Меня удивляет, почему в HttpClient не сделали метод `GetFile`. Когда народ гуглит, как скачать файл, то находят, что неудивительно, WebClient с его методами.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov наверное потому что скачивание файлов таким образом - не промышленная задача. К тому же скачать и записать на диск - это 2 задачи, которые для мелких файлов так же решаются в одну строку кода, а для больших нужен комплекс с отчетом о прогрессе и т.д. Возможно допишут метод расширения в комплект к методам типа `GetJsonAsync` и `ReadAsJsonAsync`. Но спроектировать это красиво и правильно не так то просто, быть может поэтому и нет пока.