# Многопоточное скачивание крупных файлов (~900 мб) будет ли переполнять оперативную память?

Tags: c#

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, (а точнее она у меня крутится в голове) будет ли переполняться память, если я буду отправлять большой массив байтов пользователю. Отправление данных я произвожу в json формате и там же храню данные о файле и его содержимое (байтовый массив). Общий размер выходит в районе 3-5 ГБ. Если у пользователей будет всего 2-4 ГБ оперативки?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86

Comment: И что это отменяет? если у пользователя не хватит физической памяти(если вдруг вы попытаетесь все запихнуть в оперативку, но зачем не понимаю) - используется подкачка, и часть памяти жесткого диска будет использована как **очень** медленная ОЗУ :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков я пересмотрел статью, и поэтому удалил пост ) То-есть Вы предлагаете использовать виртуальную память, верно?

Comment: Нет конечно, я такой глупости не предлагал, я предлагал не держать такой объем в ОЗУ, и я досих пор не вижу необходимости в этом :)

Comment: Что ж у вас за данные такие? Мне кажется, тут нужно в первую очередь подумать, как уменьшить количество хранимых и передаваемых данных. Наверняка это можно как-то сделать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3 гига в JSON. С форматом передачи данных явно что-то пошло не так. Пытаетесь решить проблему, которую сами же создали. Файлы должны передаваться через ответ сервера по типу файла, а не через JSON. В JSON можете положить ссылку на файл, чтобы клиент мог его скачать отдельно.

Сериализуя двоичный файл в текстовый формат типа Base64, дополнительно увеличиваете размер ответа. Я как пользователь с 5-мегабитным LTE каналом связи и 100-гигами лимита трафика в месяц, спасибо бы за такое точно не сказал.

Ну и конечно же, то что должно скачиваться на диск, нет никакого смысла хранить в оперативной памяти ни одной лишней секунды. Обычный [буфер чтения и Stream](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1134235/373567) - вполне себе качественный вариант скачки файлов без хранения их в памяти.

Объем оперативы при этом значения не имеет совершенно никакого, даже файл весом в пару мегабайт нет смысла в память затягивать целиком, если точка его назначения - диск.

> Если у пользователей будет всего 2-4 ГБ оперативки?

А если у пользователя вообще телефон или наручные часы, или чайник для кипячения воды? Если вы не пишете сложные игры, требующие загрузки кучи ресурсов в память, то вас в принципе не должно волновать, сколько у пользователя памяти. Представьте, что ее приблизительно вообще нет. Экономьте ресурсы компа и нервы пользователя.

Comment: Ответ вынес как решение.