# Filestream правильный порядок кода при записи?

Tags: c#, winforms, рефакторинг, filestream

Воощем ребят смотрите,
есть код: `1`

```
...
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int currentPosition = 0;
int byteReceieved;

while ((byteReceieved = srcStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
  currentPosition += byteReceieved;//1
  TotalProgress.Value = ... //2
  dstStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteReceieved);  
}
```

И такой: `2`

```
...
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int currentPosition = 0;
int byteReceieved;

while ((byteReceieved = srcStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{    
  dstStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteReceieved);
  currentPosition += byteReceieved;//1 
  TotalProgress.Value = ... //2
}
```

И вот такой: `3`

```
...
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int currentPosition = 0;
int byteReceieved;

while ((byteReceieved = srcStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{   
  currentPosition += byteReceieved; //1
  dstStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteReceieved);   
  TotalProgress.Value = ... //2
}
```

Суть вопроса: какой из этих примеров верный, `1 - когда мы рапортуем и считаем до записи в файл`, `2 - после записи в файл`, и `3 - считаем до, рапортуем после?`. И есть ли тут разница вообще? P.S. В интернете кучу примеров просмотрел, но люди везде по-разному реализуют. Поэтому и не пришел к единому правильному выводу.

Comment: нет никакой разницы. С точки зрений логики, может быть, логичнее 2й вариант: сначала записать данные, потом обновить позицию, и потом об этом отчитаться. Но по сути разницы 0

Comment: А с чего этот вопрос вообще возник? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1134235/373567

Comment: Вариант 2. Потенциально проблема может возникнуть в строке, где запись идёт, и "рапортовать" следует когда запись прошла успешно. ПС: currentPosition случайно не дублирует функционал Stream.Position?

Comment: @Qwer - нет, это просто название переменной.

Comment: @Qwer - И да кстати, Вы правы, если что-то пойдет не так `при записи` и возникнет `исключение`. А мы при этом уже отрапортовали пользователю на этом этапе, о том, что этот этап прошли. Тогда да, получается нужно использовать `2 вариант`. Вы кстати можете написать ответ, а я его помечу как верный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 2. Потенциально проблема может возникнуть в строке, где запись идёт, и "рапортовать" следует когда запись прошла успешно.

ПС: **currentPosition** случайно не дублирует функционал **Stream.Position**?

Comment: Нет, не дублирует, я Вам уже ответил чуть выше )