# Загрузка файла с помощью HttpClient

Tags: c#, httpclient

Нужно заменить эти простые строки `WebClient-а` на `HttpClient`

```
WebClient WebClient = new WebClient();
string link = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id="; // в ссылке убран id
string DownloadFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName("Test.7z");
WebClient.DownloadFile(link, Path.Combine(TempPath, DownloadFileName));
```

Как это можно сделать, чтобы была асинхронная загрузка? Долго ищу решение, но нужное для меня еще не нашел. (нужен простой код загрузки, чтобы он повторял код выше, но уже на `httpClient`)

Просьба не писать, что я тупой или мое любимое: "изучите тему, а потом пишите код" - подробно изучать `httpClient` ради загрузки одного файла считаю не целесообразным делом.

Comment: Обратите внимание на главную разницу: `WebClient` создаётся на каждый запрос, а `HttpClient` должен переиспользоваться один на всё время работы приложения. _Долго ищу решение, но нужное для меня еще не нашел._ - плохо искали, пример по ссылке вверху в синем блоке.

Comment: Если нужен пример пожирнее, например с докачкой недокачанного и отчётом о прогрессе, то это тоже у нас есть - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1134235/373567

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
using var client = new HttpClient(); 
var link = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=";
var path = Path.GetTempFileName();
await using var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(link);
await using var file = File.Create(path);
await stream.CopyToAsync(file);
```

Вариант без создания промежуточного массива, теоретически эффективнее, т.к. временный массив можно не создавать только для того чтобы записать его в файл.

P.S. также каздый раз создавать `HttpClient` не рекомендуется, для примера или тестового кода это подойдет, но для реальных кейсов, например использвания в `ASP.NET Core` лучше воспользоваться `IHttpClientFactory`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0