# Создать список задач и выполнить всё сразу

Tags: c#, async-await, .net-core, task

Имеется .NET 7 (WPF) приложение, в котором пользователь может скачивать некоторые файлы. Мой план заключается в том, чтобы сначала собрать задачи скачивания в список (чанк) и уже потом сразу весь чанк задач выполнить. Но, видимо, я упускаю что-то очень важное, ибо скачивание файла начинается сразу же после создания задачи.

Метод скачивания, пробовал и цепочку и async/await:

```cs
public Task DownloadAsync(PostModel post, string saveDirectory, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var filePath = Path.Combine(saveDirectory, $"{post.Id}{Path.GetExtension(post.FileUrl)}");
    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        return _httpClient.GetAsync(post.FileUrl, cancellationToken)
            .ContinueWith(x => x.Result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync(cancellationToken)
                .ContinueWith(y => File.WriteAllBytesAsync(filePath, y.Result, cancellationToken), cancellationToken), cancellationToken);

        //using var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(post.FileUrl, cancellationToken);
        //var responseByteArray = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync(cancellationToken);
        //await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(filePath, responseByteArray, cancellationToken);
    }

    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Цикл, где используются скачивание (упростил для размещения):

```cs
var chunkDownloadTasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var post in posts.Posts)
{
    var downloadTask = (GetContentTypeFromUrl(post.FileUrl) switch
    {
        ContentType.Image when settings.IncludeImages => _downloadService.DownloadAsync(post, GetFolder(settings.SavePath, ref imagesFolder, "Images"), cancellationToken),
        ContentType.Video when settings.IncludeVideo => _downloadService.DownloadAsync(post, GetFolder(settings.SavePath, ref videoFolder, "Video"), cancellationToken),
        ContentType.Gif when settings.IncludeGifs => _downloadService.DownloadAsync(post, GetFolder(settings.SavePath, ref gifFolder, "Gif"), cancellationToken),
        _ => null
    })?.ContinueWith(_ =>
    {
        status.Downloaded++;
        progress.Report(status);
    }, cancellationToken);

    if (downloadTask == null)
    {
        status.Skipped++;
        progress.Report(status);

        continue;
    }

    chunkDownloadTasks.Add(downloadTask);

    if (chunkDownloadTasks.Count == ChunkSize)
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(chunkDownloadTasks.ToArray());
        chunkDownloadTasks.Clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так а суть проблемы то в чем, медленно качается, или что? Зачем эти все истории с чанками и т.д.? По коду - вы смешиваете `async/await` и TPL `.ContinueWith`, это затрудняет написание стабильного решения и усложняет отладку. Метод скачивания почему-то у вас всасывает все данные в память, зачем?

Далее, можно организовать Producer/Consumer, например вы хотите, чтобы одновременно качалось не более 8 файлов.

Кстати, покажу пример настройки `_httpClient`.

```
private static readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new(new HttpClientHandler { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.All })
{ 
    DefaultRequestVersion = HttpVersion.Version20
};
```

Создаю consumer

```
private async Task PostDownloaderAsync(string saveDirectory, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ChannelReader<PostModel> reader)
{
    const int maxConcurrency = 8;
    using SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new(maxConcurrency);
    ConcurrentBag<Task> tasks = new();
    await foreach (PostModel post in reader.ReadAllAsync(cancellationToken))
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Task task = DownloadAsync(post, saveDirectory, cancellationToken, semaphore, tasks);
        tasks.Add(task);
        _ = task.ContinueWith(t => tasks.TryTake(t));
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

private async Task DownloadAsync(PostModel post, string saveDirectory, CancellationToken cancellationToken, SemaphoreSlim semaphore)
{
    try
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(saveDirectory, $"{post.Id}{Path.GetExtension(post.FileUrl)}");
        using var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(post.FileUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        using var stream = await response
            .EnsureSuccessStatusCode() // бросить исключение если сервер ответил ошибкой
            .Content
            .ReadAsStreamAsync(cancellationToken)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
        using var fs = File.Create(filePath);
        await stream.CopyToAsync(fs, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

Кстати, здесь есть [пример метода загрузки с отчётом о прогрессе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1134235/373567) и возможностью докачки недокачанного файла.

Далее, создаю канал передачи данных между генератором операций скачивания (producer) и исполнителем (consumer) и запускаю исполнителя

```
Channel<PostModel> channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<PostModel>();
Task consumerTask = PostDownloaderAsync(saveDirectory, cancellationToken, channel.Reader);
```

Чтобы запусть операцию, нужно вызвать

```
await channel.Writer.WriteAsync(post, cancellationToken);
```

Чтобы остановить consumer, нужно вызвать

```
channel.Writer.Complete();
await consumerTask;
```

Ну или отменить `CancellationTokenSource`.

Вот и получится, что как только выполняете `WriteAsync`, сразу же начинается загрузка, но ждать её окончания не придётся. Если же вы закинете в очередь очень много загрузок сразу, то максимум одновременно будет качаться 8 штук, и как только очередная загрузка завершится, сразу же начнётся следующая, и так пока всё не скачается.

Вы можете вызвать `Complete` до завершения всех загрузок в любое время, хоть сразу после добавления всех задач, `consumerTask` завершится как всё докачается. `Complete` не прерывает процесс загрузок, он только сообщает каналу, что добавление в очередь завершено, чтобы цикл `await foreach` нормально завершился как только канал опустеет.

Comment: А зачем тут хитрый приём с удалением таски из коллекции по завершении? Память экономите? )

Comment: @CrazyElf никто не сказал, что задач будет ограниченное количество. Можно конечно выбросить эту строчку, если их не много. Вдруг это какой-то парсер, который качает файлы неделями.

Comment: Не, так то приём интересный, но ситуация, когда таска сама себя из коллекции удаляет не кажется мне методологически правильной. Как-то это по-другому должно делаться, мне кажется. Объекты более высокого уровня должны управлять объектами ниже по иерархии, а не наоборот. Но возможно, я ошибаюсь. Не может, например, быть такого, что `ContinueWith` отработает уже после `WhenAll` и выхода из функции? Да, вероятность этого мала и ещё меньше вероятность того, что локальная коллекция `tasks` успеет утилизироваться. Но такая вероятность, мне кажется, есть и в результате будет что-то нехорошее.

Comment: @CrazyElf ну ок, можно написать обертку, которая стартует таску, эвэйтит и удаляет, в итоге получится то же самое, только с лишней прослойкой. Методологически задача внутри метода скачивания ничего не знает ни про коллекци, не про то что надо себя откуда-то удалить.

Comment: > а суть проблемы то в чем, медленно качается, или что? - Так это и не суть, но чанками качать маленькие файлы быстрее. > Метод скачивания почему-то у вас всасывает все данные в память, зачем? - Знаю, это пока что playground, просто играюсь с разными вещами. Я не эксперт, чтобы сразу идеальный код выдать, решаю проблемы по одной. Но спасибо за ваш ответ, буду изучать

Comment: А что за глобальный семафор (_semaphore) или это опечатка?

Comment: @Jagailo опечатка, поправил. Код на коленке писал.